# condition for avoiding NaN, Inf, in sensor fusion probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to compute an existence probability of an object in a sensor fusion on the high level (having from each sensor list of objects already filtered with e.g. Kalman Filter).

How to condition that computation to avoid situations of dividing by zero, obtaining NaN, Inf? Also, if *pEx_in_new* is almost 1, then alpha will be huge, increasing output, and increasing it enormously in each later cycle, so that the object will live forever. How to prevent it?

There is this formulae:

```
LR_G_old = pEx_out_old/(1-pEx_out_old);
alpha = pEx_in_old/(pEx_in_old*(1-pEx_in_new));
LR_G_new = LR_G_old * alpha;
pEx_out_new= LR_G_new /(1+LR_G_new );
```

The idea is that pEx_in is some probability existence of local object, which was fused into the global pEx_out, and its probability influences that global one. old would mean values from previous cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to add a value of $\epsilon$ to the denominator to prevent overflow conditions.  By the way, your expression for alpha is inefficient and may simply be written as alpha = 1/(1-pEx_in_new).  However, to prevent overflow, write instead alpha = 1/(1-pEx_in_new + EPSILON), where 1/EPSILON is the largest tolerable value of alpha.

Comment: My suspicion is that the expression is an error, and it should be "pEx_in_old/(pEx_in_new*(1-pEx_in_new))".

Comment: @martycohen: likely, but I am just going with what the OP has given us.  In any case, my comment would still apply.